# Binding Multiple IP addresses to Master in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, network-programming, distributed-computing

I am trying to set up Apache Spark with the following systems:

1 Master Node(having public IP, local IP)
Slave Node-3(having public IP, local IP)
Slave node-2(having Local IP)

The configuration is such that the Master Node and Slave Node-3 communicate via public IP's whereas Slave node-2 communicates with the other two Nodes via localIP's.

The problem I am facing is, that since the Master Node binds to a public IP, Slave Node-2 is unable to connect to the Master via it's local IP this giving a connection refused error, however Slave Node-3 is able to communicate with the Master Node without any difficulty.

Is there a way as to how can i allow communication between Master Node and Slave Node-2 or as to how can i bind multiple addresses to the Master Node, for e.g such a configuration is possible in Hadoop where we can have the namenode bind to multiple hosts.

Thank you

Comment: "The configuration is such that the Master Node and Slave Node-3 communicate via public IP's whereas Slave node-2 communicates with the other two Nodes via public IP's." -- I assume you meant for 'public' to be 'private' for one of these cases due to your use of 'whereas'?

Comment: @LiamKelly Sorry! Edited.

Answer (score 0):

If you bind the Master to '[0.0.0.0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.0.0.0)' or all local addresses, then the master should be able to communicate with Node-2 via the private network and Node-3 on the public network.

Comment: I did bind the Master to '0.0.0.0' via SPARK_MASTER_HOST property but now all the worker nodes show a connection refused error, i.e no worker is able to connect to the master.

Comment: Ok, first ensure that your routing rules allow for communication by pinging both devices from the master node. Then check your firewall rules will allow the type of connection on both interfaces.

Comment: I am able to ping to both the nodes from the master, and also as stated above I managed to get this done with hadoop, however there seems to be an issue with spark